# Umbraco Cms gives error "Provider must implement the class 'System.Web.Security.RoleProvider'"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, umbraco, membership-provider

I have developed an Umbraco CMS site which is using custom controller (as mentioned [here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/mvc/custom-controllers))

Now I have some Mvc Application whose some behavior (Action and Controllers) I am porting into Umbraco Cms. I needed the login functionality and as soon as I add the providers in web.config this crashes at runtime.

**Error message:**

> > Provider must implement the class 'System.Web.Security.RoleProvider'.

**Below is the web.config settings**

```xml
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="2147483647" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="1" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
    </providers>
</membership>
<!-- added by NH to support membership providers in access layer -->
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UmbracoRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoRoleProvider"/>
    </providers>
</roleManager>
<!-- Sitemap provider-->
<siteMap defaultProvider="UmbracoSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="UmbracoSiteMapProvider" type="umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.UmbracoSiteMapProvider" defaultDescriptionAlias="description" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
    </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Googling and Binging both not helping as this seems generic error message and might have to do something related to Umbraco settings or Membership Api (As I am trying to add more than one providers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue now. What I was doing was bit of wrong, I was adding one of the `profile` provider in `sitemap` provider's tag.

Corrected tags structure is as below:

```xml
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="2147483647" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="1" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<!-- added by NH to support membership providers in access layer -->
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UmbracoRoleProvider">
    <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
    <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</profile>
```